# Certificate Auto-Enrollment for AD User When Requested by Service Account

Tags: active-directory, certificate-authority

I have one AD server and Microsoft Certification Authority in a domain. I also have a service account in AD which can request for client authentication certificate to be generated for any user. Expectation is when the certificate is generated, same is to be published to the respective user object in the AD. I followed https://docs.druva.com/Knowledge_Base/inSync/How_To/How_to_set_up_automatic_certificate_enrollment_in_Active_Directory for creation of certificate template and GPO.

The problem I'm facing is that, the certificates are published to the service account itself instead of the user account. I can share any specific configuration details if required.

Could somebody please help me understand what am I missing and to resolve the issue? Thanks.